# Idiomatic way to match a regular expression in C++

Tags: c++, regex, string

I want to compare two strings in C++:

1. There is a function `getName()` that returns a string.
2. Now I can write `Out << getName();` this will print the string.
3. However I want to print the string **only** if its value is `arpit` or `arpit*N*` where *N* is an integer. I **don't** want to print it if its value is `arpita`, `arpitx`, where *N* is something other than an integer or an empty string.

I know this can be easily done, but I want to do this in a minimal number of lines.

What I have done so far is:

```
char name1[] = getName();
char name2[] = "arpit";
for (int x = 0; x <= 4; x++){
    if (name1[x] == name2[x]) continue;
    else return ( Out << "not equal") ;
    }
while(name1[x] ! = "\0"){
    if(isdigit(name1[x])
    x++;
    else return (Out << "not equal") ;
    }
Out << getName();
```

**UPDATE 1**
`getName()` returns a string until it encounters white space, and it will not return any line or 2 or more words.

Comment: Hmm. What have you tried? Show some effort, *pretty please*. Just asking for solutions like that is not the purpose of SO.

Comment: `std::string s = getName(); if (s.size() >= 5 && s.substring(0,5) == "arpit") Out << s;`

Comment: What about `boost::starts_with(getName(), "arpit")`?

Comment: Poor form to work around the question title filter with "comaparison".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code that already works. Would be a better fit on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @razlebe It won't compile, so I wouldn't call it correct.

Comment: Fair enough @James. But the OP's stating that he has working code, so regardless of the state of what's been posted here, I still think codereview is the better site to post his actual question.

Comment: @razlebe I don't know.  I'd consider questions concerning what is effective and idiomatic C++ valid here.  (His code is clearly not idiomatic.  And of course, his second update is lying about something: either he's not using the code he has posted, or it doesn't compile, and so cannot work.  Who knows.)

Comment: @razlebe And he's rescinded Update 2.  It's hard to say anything about a question that keeps changing.

Comment: Just out of curiousity: how is `getName()` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have C++11:

```
static std::regex const matcher( "arpit\\d*" );

if ( regex_match( name, matcher ) ) {
    //  matches...
}
```

If you don't have C++11, boost::regex is practically identical.

If you don't have C++11, and you can't use boost:

```
if ( name1.size() >= name2.size()
    && std::equal( name2.begin(), name2.end(), name1.begin() )
    && std::find_if( name1.begin() + name2.size(),
                     name1.end(),
                     []( unsigned char ch ) { return !isdigit( ch ); }
                    ) == name1.end() )
    //  matches...
}
```

For the rest, your code has quite a few errors, and shouldn't
compile.  In particular, there is *nothing* which `getName()`
could return which can be used to initialize a `char []`; the
type of a string in C++ is `std::string`, and your variables
should be:

```
std::string name1( getName() );
std::string name2( "arpit" );
```

(except that you need better names.  The second might be
something like `reference` or `header`, for example.)

And of course, it's undefined behavior to call `isdigit` with
a `char`; you have to convert to `unsigned char` first.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto s = getName();
if(s.size() >= 5 && s.substr(0,5) == "arpit")
    Out << s;
```

Comment: Does `getName` return a reference to something existing elsewhere?  He said it returned a string.  Unless it returns a reference, assigning it to a reference is just excess verbiage (and can slow the program down slightly).

Comment: And this is blatant abuse of `auto`, and could even make the program incorrect (if e.g. `getName()` returns a `char const*`.  Even if `getName` returns an `std::string`, it's unnecessary obfuscation.

Comment: And finally, of course, this doesn't do what he asked for, since it will also print `"arpita"`, etc.  (Not to mention that there are far more effective ways of comparing the first 5 characters than by creating a substring.)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::set<std::string> m_allowed_strings;

std::string validate_string(const string & s)
{
    if(m_allowed_strings.find(s) != m_allowed_strings.end())
            return s;
    return "";
}

cout << validate_string(getName());
```

Comment: Seems like overkill. And do we need to call `getName` twice? We haven't been told what it is actually doing, it may return each line from a file of names, for instance.

Comment: I don't think using a `set` here is possible, and it's certainly not reasonable.  Although his examples only have 1 digit after the `"arpit"`, his attempt at coding suggests that there can be more; which means that the set of valid strings is infinite.